# Node js - How to correctly use make async network calls within a module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, facebook, asynchronous

So for part of a project I am working on I have created a module that uses the Facebook graph API to make calls and return JSON data. I can console.log() the data within the method out fine and it's all good.

But I can not return the values from the methods, so I tried to use the 'async' npm module. I have followed the examples on the website, but still am struggling to get everything working, spent all day on it so far and still things arn't looking any clearer.

**So what I am asking is:**

- Firstly I need to call the method that sets the authentication_token for the fbgraph api before I can do anything else
- Then I need to call each of the functions (in any order) and get the json result for each and add it to one big json result
- Finally I need to get this one big json result back into my origional javascript page (even though it's currently in a module), how would I invoke it?

Here is a snippit of my original module (only works with console.log, can't return)

```
module.exports = {
        /**
         * Pass the access token to the fbgraph module
         * and call other methods to populate
         */
         setUp: function (access_token) {
             graph.setAccessToken(access_token);
         },

        /**
         * Fetches users basic info:
         * Age, Gender, Hometown, Relationship status
         */
        getBasicInfo: function(){
            graph.get("/me/", function(err, res) {
                var result = {
                    'age'       : _calculateAge(res.birthday),
                    'gender'    : res.gender,
                    'hometown'  : res.hometown.name,
                    'relationship_status' : res.relationship_status
                };
                //console.log(result);
                return result;
            }, function(){ console.log("DONE");});
        },
        /**
         * Creates a body of text as a string
         * made up of all the users status updates
         */
        getPosts: function(){
            graph.get("/me/feed?limit="+PHOTO_LIMIT, function(err, res) {
                var posts = "";
                for(var i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
                    var obj = res.data[i];
                    if(obj.message!=undefined) posts += obj.message+"\n";
                }
                //console.log(posts);
                return {'posts':posts};
            });
        },
        /**
         * Fetches a single dimension string array of
         * photos user is tagged in
         */
        getPhotos: function(){
            graph.get("/me/photos?limit="+PHOTO_LIMIT, function(err, res) {
                var photos = [];
                for(var i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
                    var obj = res.data[i];
                    photos.push(obj.source); // .source is full size image, .picture is a thumbnail
                }
                return {'photos': photos};
            });
        }
     }
```

The rest of this module continues in a similar way 
I have tried using parralel async

```
module.exports = {
    getFacebookInfo: function (access_token) {
        results = {};
        setUp(access_token);
        async.parallel([
            facebookDataRequests.getBasicInfo(),
            facebookDataRequests.getPosts()
```

Any guidence on how I should structure this would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you structure this differently. It's not necessary to make three calls to Facebook, because you can get the info in one call as well.

So, what I'd do:

1. Call the Facebook Graph API using field expansion
2. Format results
3. Return results

Also, I'd advise you to use a Promise library like [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

Something like this (untested!):

```
module.exports = {
    getFacebookInfo: function (access_token) {

        setUp(access_token);

        function setUp(access_token) {
             graph.setAccessToken(access_token);
         }

        function getFBInfo() {
            var deferred = Q.deferred();
            graph.get("/me?fields=id,name,birthday,gender,hometown,relationship_status,feed.limit(25),photos.limit(25)", function(err, res) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                deferred.resolve(res);
            });
            return deferred.promise
        }

        function handleResult(result) {
            var deferred = Q.deferred();

            result.posts = result.feed.data
            delete result.feed.data;

            result.photos = result.photos.data
            delete result.photos.data;

            deferred.resolve(result);

            return deferred.promise
        }

        Q.fcall(getFBInfo)
        .then(handleResult)
        .then(function(result) {
            return result;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle any error from all above steps
        })
        .done();
    }
}
```

In your main file:

```
var FB = require('./path/to/file/above');

var results = FB.getFacebookInfo('ACCESS_TOKEN_SDAIOFHIOSDHFOSO');
```

Comment: Hi Tobi, thanks so much for this. It is much clearer than what I'd initially written, defiantly a far better way of doing this - Thanks!
Just reading about Q now, looks good.
How should I call this from my main js file?